# how to retrieve the row value on click

Tags: jquery

```
 var RowClick = function() {
    ("#Grid").click(
         var  s = $("#Grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow').toString();
         alert(s);
            $("#showgrid").load('/Inventory/Products/List/' + s));
    };
```

on RowClick i am trying to get the value of that row to send throw URL..
to access this Row value in my Actionresult method. 
but I am getting null value for the row? is this right what I am doing here?

When I am doing something like this..

```
var value;
$("#Grid").click(function(e) {
                    var row = jQuery(e.target).parent();
                    value= row.attr("id");
});
    var RowClick = function() {
    ("#Grid").click(
            $("#showgrid").load('/Inventory/Products/List/' + value));
    };
```

on alert I am getting the row value perfectly but in my action result method It's showing me null value?

```
Public Actionresult List(string value)
{
  return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) takes a function as a parameter, so maybe what you want is this:

```
var RowClick = function() {
    var  s = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow').toString();
    alert(s);
    $("#showgrid").load('/Inventory/Products/List/' + s));
}
$('#Grid').click(RowClick)
```

Alternately, just pass in your function as an anonymous function:

```
$('#Grid').click(function(){
    var  s = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow').toString();
    alert(s);
    $("#showgrid").load('/Inventory/Products/List/' + s));
});
```

It would be worthwhile to look at [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) as an alternate syntax to bind events, it comes up if you want to bind the same function to different events.

Comment: but I am getting s value null?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options and http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods ? `getGridParam` returns an array. I suggest using Firebug in Firefox to see if there are errors in the page that may be a problem.